# Using same session for 2 different devices (code igniter 3 application)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an application where I need to access the session data of another client. I have a cart type application and another device (iPad in this case) needs to read the session data. I know I could probably store the cart data in a shared resource;but that would require changing a lot of code. The iPad device would simply display what it is the cart.

The cart data is stored in a session.

My sessions are in a database so I suppose I could query the database and have the end user pick the session to mirror; but I am not sure I like this idea either.

Should I not use sessions for this; our at least store shared data NOT in the session?

Comment: Storing the information in a database would be the best way to do this. Session data is stored client side and is not meant to be accessible by other users. I would instead create a database that would store the cart data rather than a session. Then just remove the row from the database when you are done with the cart data (if preferred).

Comment: Thanks that is pretty much what I concluded. session data is not stored client side in most cases unless it is a small amount of data and cookies are used.